# How Pod status becomes MatchNodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

In our staging environment, there is a defect reported. After kubernetes updated, some Pods status become 'MatchNodeSelector'.

But I have no idea why and how some Pods become 'MatchNodeSelector'. So I do some research 'if a Pod have a field 'nodeSelector' and doesn't have any node have this label. These Pods will become 'MatchNodeSelector'.

But I cannot reproduce it. The Pods status always becomes 'Pending', not 'MatchNodeSelector'.
So my question is that how can I make a Pod status become 'MatchNodeSelector'?

Comment: Maybe set the nodeselector to an existing node name, than stop the node

Comment: I have tried this way. The Pod status didn't become MatchNodeSelector.

Comment: Which version of k8s you were using and to which you have updated it. Also how you have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to reproduce this by:

1. For any running pod with no node affinity provided, export its yaml or json with `kubectl get po -o json --export`. Do note the node on which it is running
2. Delete the pod.
3. Explicitly provide the node affinity to a node which is not the same as the previous node on which it was running. Add it in spec with something like this:

> ```
>  "spec": {
>      "affinity": {
>         "nodeAffinity": {
>           "requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution": {
>             "nodeSelectorTerms": [
>               {
>                 "matchExpressions": [
>                   {
>                     "key": "kubernetes.io/hostname",
>                     "operator": "In",
>                     "values": [
>                       "new node name"
>                     ]
>                   }
>                 ]
>               }
>             ]
>           }
>         }
>       }
>     }
> ```

4. Create the pod with `kubectl create -f pod.json`
5. Pod status is now MatchNodeSelector.

---

This is because there is a `node` option in the same spec as well, which also needs to be changed. It is not removed by the --export option and would still have the older node name in that field.

I am guessing if it conflicts with whatever node name you gave in affinity, it will result in this status.

These are the versions:
`Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:17:39Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.1", GitCommit:"eec55b9ba98609a46fee712359c7b5b365bdd920", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-12-13T10:31:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Answer (score 0):

`MatchNodeSelector` is a status of a pod that I've observed after worker node restarts. It appears on pods which use the `.spec.nodeSelector` stanza. What happens:

1. kubelet starts and loads the labels from the command-line, e.g. `/usr/bin/kubelet ... --node-labels=node-kind.foo.io/master=`
2. during a start-up among other things kubelet asks etcd for:

   - list of the additional node labels that were created via API in the past
   - list of the pods to run on the node
3. sometimes it starts bringing up the pods before the full set of labels is applied on the node
4. as a result, if your pod is supposed to be started on this node, and its `.spec.NodeSelector` is using labels from etcd/API, not from command-line, kubelet sees a mismatch between the expectations of the pod and the labels applied on this node (because the full refresh from etcd hasn't been processed yet)
5. typically shortly after the full set of labels is merged (from cmd line and from etcd) and the next pods starts correctly

References: [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52902) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/71907)